# Dark current versus temperature in phototransistors

Tags: phototransistor

Typically dark current rises quite rapidly with respect to temperature. If I have two of the same type of phototransistor, how well is the rise in dark current matched between them?

Comment: This is probably best asked of the supplier.

Comment: @Andyaka That depends on whether it is a property of physics or manufacturing

Comment: The *ratio* of dark currents in two devices of the same type vs. temperature is primarily a physics issue, but the absolute dark current is subject to manufacturing variations, although the lot to lot variations may be better than the last time I used some.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the dark currents are not matched at all.

A slightly more (or maybe less) useful answer is that the maximum dark current spec provides a matching number if you want to use it that way. That is, if the maximum dark current is specified as 1 nA, then any two PDs have dark current which is matched to 1 nA. Probably not a useful concept, but still....